LinkedIn API error 403: /v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=handleString
#linkedin
When I am calling API https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=handleString&handleString=${SOME_EMAIL}&oauth2_access_token=${TOKEN}, I got below error:
[{"status":403,"serviceErrorCode":100,"code":"ACCESS_DENIED","message":"Not enough permissions to access: clientAwareMemberHandles.FINDER-handleString.NO_VERSION"}]

In the error code, it does not tell me which permission do I miss. Please help.
I have acquired below permissions with my LinkedIn app:
r_basicprofile,rw_ads,rw_organization_admin,profile,openid,email,w_member_social,r_1st_connections_size
I am able to get an access token with no problem. In order to test if my account has any permission, I tested with the other API https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token=${TOKEN}. I am able to get the expected result.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The error is due to missing permissions. According to the official LinkedIn docs, you need one of those:

r_emailaddress: Retrieve the primary email address.
r_primarycontact: Retrieve primary member handles (email or phone).

